# Im confused to the significance of [:,1] in the following line of code of a Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, indexing, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

I am running a Logistic regression using 2 features, cylinders and years for a multiclass classification problem.

After applying the training, we are applying the model to test data:

```
for origin in unique_origins:
  # Select testing features.
   X_test = test[features]   
   # Compute probability of observation being in the origin.
   testing_probs[origin] = models[origin].predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

I am confused to what the [:,1] part does to the code, if anyone could kindly explain.

There is a hint which says:
testing_probs[1] should return the probability returned from model 1 for each observation.

However i do not understand what it is trying to explain.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: predict_proba returns the probability that the model thinks it has label 0 or label 1 for binary classification problem. If you are using predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], it is picking up only the probability of label 1. I am not sure if it would work for multiclass classification as it would always pick up label 1 and not label 2 or 3 or others. For multiclass classification, the best option is to pick up the label with highest probability (using np.argmax).

Answer (score 0):

array[:,1] is equivalent to array[:][1] for many types of array.
Also it means that you keep all the data on the first dimension, but you pick only the 2nd data on the second dimension :

```py
a = np.array([[0,1], [2,3]])
a[:][1] 

>>> array([2, 4])
```

In your case, the first dimension represent the number of the prediction and the second dimension the number of the class.
Also, when calling :
*models[origin].predict_proba(X_test)[i,j]*
You get the prediction for the ith input of the jth class.

So, *models[origin].predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]* means you want the predictions for all of your inputs but only the result for the 2nd class (as the first class is indexed at 0)!